# use Parameterized Thread Start C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Whether the method that is called in `ParameterizedThreadStart` can use more than one parameter?

```
class Fungsi
{
    public void satu(int a, int b) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 20; x++)
        {
            tampil(a, b, '=', x);
            b++;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
     }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fungsi a = new Fungsi();
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        Thread ab = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(a.satu));
        ab.Start(10,1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

why `Thread ab = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(a.satu));`

how to use ParameterizedThreadStart?

and I want to create 4 Multithread with one method

Comment: Pass them as an array? Or a class of parameters?

Comment: You can just use anonymous function: `Thread ab = new Thread(() => satu(10, 1)); ab.Start();`

Comment: Parameters @BugFinder

Comment: Can one method to create 4 Thread??

Answer (score 1):

Given the method

```
void Worker(string a, int b){}
```

for .NET 2.0 you need to use delegates:

```
ThreadStart start = delegate { Worker("bla", 10); };
Thread t = new Thread(start);
t.Start();
```

for later .NET versions you could use the anonymous function:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Worker("bla", 10));
t.Start();
```

or since .NET 4 you could use TPL Tasks:

```
Task t = new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => Worker("bla", 10));
```